# Trouble getting started with Django - ImportError: No module named management

Tags: python, django, windows, heroku, virtualenv

First, I've read all the threads I could find that have similar titles. This is bound to be a repost, but I've looked and didn't find it.

Second, here's my setup and what I've done. I'm on `Windows 7`. I'm following the getting started guide for `Heroku` at: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django. I used the guide they provided for installing `Python`, `virtualenv`, `distribute`, and `pip` (http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/). I installed `Python 2.7`, with no other version present using the Windows installer. I then followed the steps laid out in the guide on `Heroku` exactly as they are. I had to use the alternate method for installing `psycopg2`, but it seemed to work fine.

The problem came up then I got to the step where I am supposed to run

```
django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .
```

I get this error when I try to run the command:

```
(venv) C:\Users\myname\projectdir>django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\projectdir\venv\Scripts\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
ImportError: No module named django.core
```

I have tried manually running Python from within the virtual environment and importing django, django.core, and the line specified in the error text, and all work:

```
(venv) C:\Users\myname\projectdir>python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> from django import core
>>> import django.core
>>> from django.core import management
>>>
```

I tried using pip to uninstall everything, deleting the virtual environment, deleting the project folder, then starting over. The same errors happened.

It's probably something simple, but I can't figure out what I'm missing. Any ideas?

edit - Also, I tried changing the command to :

```
django-admin.py startproject projectdir .
```

but this had the same result.

Then I tried:

```
python C:\Users\myname\projectdir\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\bindjango-admin.py startproject projectdir .
```

But I got:

```
python: can't open file 'C:\Users\wtodom\hdj\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\bindj
ango-admin.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: It seems like Django is not on your sys.path. Also, the last thing you tried has a typo - it should be `bin\django-admin.py` not `bindjango-admin.py`.

Comment: @DanHoerst Yep, fixing that typo got it to work, and you're probably right about Django not being in the path. Do I add it the normal way I'd add something to my path, or is there something special i need to do since I'm using virtualenv?

Comment: @DanHoerst Also, given that path above, what exactly do I need to add? I'm sorry for being so needy, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Check out this answer for how to add things to the `PYTHONPATH` on Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7. Since you are able to `import django` from the shell, it seems that you at least have django in your app folder `C:\Users\myname\projectdir` otherwise you would get an error. If you open a shell from a different folder in the venv, can you import django?

Comment: @DanHoerst Adding to the `PYTHONPATH` looks like it will work but I haven't done it yet.

As far as imports go, I can import from other folders within the venv. (I tried it from the project root, then i tried it from a subfolder that wasn't a part of Django's path.)

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit and comments. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I had typed the path wrong (left out a single `\`), but now it works. How can I avoid having to type the entire filepath to the `django-admin.py` file every time?

@DanHoerst wrote:

> Check out this answer for how to add things to the `PYTHONPATH` on Windows: [How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7). Since you are able to `import django` from the shell, it seems that you at least have django in your app folder `C:\Users\myname\projectdir` otherwise you would get an error. If you open a shell from a different folder in the venv, can you import django?

The OP wrote:

> Adding to the `PYTHONPATH` looks like it will work but I haven't done it yet. As far as imports go, I can import from other folders within the venv. (I tried it from the project root, then I tried it from a subfolder that wasn't a part of Django's path.)